# How to secure a personal financial web app?

Tags: spring, security, tomcat, spring-security, https

I want to make a personal financial web app and host it in such a way so that I can access it from anywhere. I want to make it secure by having a login page. Developing the web app I want to make it a learning experience for myself. I want to use the Spring Framework and run the web app on Tomcat.

I'm not too familiar with securing a web app. From the research that I did, I think that I need to use Spring Security module. It also seems to me that I'll need to use SSL/HTTPS. I also want to make it in such a way so that there could be more than 1 user so I assume that I'll need to have a DB table with the usernames and encrypted passwords.

As you can see I'm confused about this stuff. Can I get some guidance of what to look resources I can look into? Something for a newbie in security.

Comment: Ask yourself  how much harm could possibly be done if the server is compromised. If you come to the conclusion "I could live with it", then go ahead and learn security with a financial app. If not then I'd strongly advice against the attempt, if you are not familiar with securing web apps, as you say. Especially if other parties could be harmed in the process.

Answer (score 0):

There are many. It's not possible to secure your web app 100%. If you prevent the hacker from hacking in 5 ways they may try the 6th way.

Look about SQL injections, how to properly validate form fields, error messages you wish to display on the screen. Since you have a database to store login details of user you should use hash algorithms like md5 hash to encrypt your password with a key. This way a hacker wont get hold of your password. Also look about XSS and how to prevent it. Buy SSL certificate from your hosting service and enable it.

I hope that helps!